# failed to start laravel project, forever loading at port 3000

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, composer-php

I try to run this project https://github.com/eriksape/laravel-react-hot-loader

After git clone here's what I did

```
composer install

npm install

cp .env.example .env

php artisan key:generate

gulp watch
```

Then I open localhost:3000, it forever loading. I'm new to laravel, may I know what am I missing? I don't have to launch xampp right? Because the project used webpack-dev-server.

Comment: what is the console says?

Comment: @imudin07 it just load forever, no error. Webpack is fine in my console, I got `webpack: Compiled successfully.`

Comment: anything in your storage/logs/laravel.log ?